# Maximum call stack size exceeded when trying to generate a pipe

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-cli

Ok so I'm new to angular 2+, but I don't get why this is throwing me an error. I'm trying to generate a new pipe using the angular CLI. This is what I'm trying:

```
ng generate pipe ptBacklog
```

I then get the following error:

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I'd like to know both why this is happening and how to fix it. I can manually create a new file, but I'm curious as of why this is not working. I've found similar issues online when trying to run 'ng serve' with a circular dependency on different modules. That makes sense, however, I find this to be an unrelated case. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

By the way, I'm using Angular CLI: 7.0.4

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a known issue with Angular CLI 7.0.4. There's already a GitHub issue open for this [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12928).

Answer (score 0):

Can you check 2 things: 
1. Import feature module, shouldn't be child routes.
2. Make sure you don't have same name for two components.